# Fuse ESB osgi:install running into issues

Tags: java, fuseesb, jbossfuse

Good Morning,

```
                 I downloaded the beta version of jboss fuse (jboss-fuse-6.0.0.redhat-015) and decided to try out the cbr sample.I run maven command "mvn clean install" and then started up the jboss fuse via commad line.At the karaf command line i tried to do the following
```

osgi:install -s fab:mvn:org.jboss.fuse.examples/cbr/6.0.0.redhat-015

It stays stuck at that for a while and then throws a error

Error executing command: Error installing bundles: Unable to install bundle fab:mvn:org.jboss.fuse.examples/cbr/6.0.0.redhat-015

When i look at the log file i see the following

org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jboss.fuse.examples:cbr:pom:6.0.0.redhat-015

Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.fuse.examples:project:pom:6.0.0.redhat-015 from repos1 (http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public): Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect

```
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:119)[71:org.fusesource.fabric.fab.fab-osgi:7.2.0.redhat-015]

at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:819)[71:org.fusesource.fabric.fab.fab-osgi:7.2.0.redhat-015]

at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:670)[71:org.fusesource.fabric.fab.fab-osgi:7.2.0.redhat-015]

at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:308)[71:org.fusesource.fabric.fab.fab-osgi:7.2.0.redhat-015]

at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:232)[71:org.fusesource.fabric.fab.fab-osgi:7.2.0.redhat-015]

at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:299)[71:org.fusesource.fabric.fab.fab-osgi:7.2.0.redhat-015]

... 32 more
```

Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.fuse.examples:project:pom:6.0.0.redhat-015 from repos1 (http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public): Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect

```
at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:488)[71:org.fusesource.fabric.fab.fab-osgi:7.2.0.redhat-015]

at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:190)[71:org.fusesource.fabric.fab.fab-osgi:7.2.0.redhat-015]

at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:115)[71:org.fusesource.fabric.fab.fab-osgi:7.2.0.redhat-015]

... 37 more
```

I have my local repository in a non standard location and have the value in my settings.xml file.The settings.xml file also has the path to my in company nexus repository from which i had expected the application to pull/resolve the above.I also have the following settings changed in my "org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg" file

org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.settings=file:D:/Maven/settings.xml

I am not sure why it is still going out to fusesource to resolve stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The beta artifacts for 6.0.0.redhat-015 are no longer available in the fusesource maven repository. Switching to the jboss-fuse-6.0.0.redhat-024 release will resolve the issue.

https://www.jboss.org/products/fuse.html

Answer (score 0):

Fuse doesn't read all settings from the Maven settings file. You need to change some of them in etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg config file.

Also you may want to verify the end result with Fuse command config:proplist --pid org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn